# add input dynamically symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi I am new in symfony I have a problem to use Ajax 
I have this class

```
class categorie extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $categories_choices = array(
            'VEHICULES' => array(
                '101' => 'Voitures',
                '102' => 'Motos',
                '103' => 'Vélos ',
                '104' => 'Pièces auto',
                '105' => 'Utilitaires / Véhicules commerciaux',
                '106' => 'Bateaux / Nautisme',
            ),
            'IMMOBILIER' => array(
                '201' => 'Vente / Achat',
                '202' => 'Location',
                '203' => 'Colocation',
                '204' => 'Location vacances',
                '205' => 'Garages / Parkings',
                '206' => 'Terrains',
                '207' => 'Bureaux / Commerces',

            ),


        );

        $builder->add('Categorie', 'choice',array(
            'choices' =>$categories_choices,
            'required' => true ,
            'required' => 'Le champ est obligatoire.',
            'attr' => array('onchange' => 'FormCategoryAjaxRequest(this.value)')
            ));

        $builder->add('Type', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('m' => 'Offre', 'f' => 'demande')
            ));
    }
```

My idea is to use javascript, this is my function:

```
FormCategoryAjaxRequest(ref_doc) {
    if (ref_doc==101 || ref_doc==102 {
        var DivToAdd = document.getElementById('registration');
        tempInput = document.createElement('input');
        tempInput.setAttribute("type","text");
        tempInput.setAttribute("id","hamza");
        var newlabel = document.createElement('Label');
        newlabel.setAttribute("for","hamza");
        newlabel.innerHTML = " text";
        DivToAdd.appendChild(newlabel);
        DivToAdd.appendChild(tempInput);
    }
}
```

I would like to add another input when the user chooses a category type it is simple with Ajax but I didn't find a solution any idea please?

Comment: Can you show your code from your ControllerAction used to update the choice list ? And your javascript...

Comment: my idea is to use javascript this is my function    
function FormCategoryAjaxRequest(ref_doc) {
  if (ref_doc==101 || ref_doc==102    {
    var DivToAdd = document.getElementById('registration');
          tempInput = document.createElement('input');
        tempInput.setAttribute("type","text");
            tempInput.setAttribute("id","hamza")
            var newlabel = document.createElement('Label');
            newlabel.setAttribute("for","hamza");
            newlabel.innerHTML = " text";
            DivToAdd.appendChild(newlabel);
        DivToAdd.appendChild(tempInput);
     }
      
}

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add an input with ajax, your form will send error in the validation time.

You should look for the form event listener, if you want to add input (during validation). doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

An other way is to init all the fields you need with option `'required=>false'` in your form Class, and play with visibility in javascript on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand what you want to do. So the best way to do this is :

1. Add the additionnal input in your form type :

   ```
   $builder->add('model', 'text');
   ```
2. Hide it with javascript (exemple with jQuery) :

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('input[name="model"]').hide();
   });
   ```
3. Modify your `FormCategoryAjaxRequest` function to display your field with your conditions :

   ```
   function FormCategoryAjaxRequest(ref_doc) {
       if (ref_doc==101 || ref_doc==102 {
           $('input[name="model"]').show();
       }
   }
   ```

With this it should work as expected. To be perfect, you can add a `NotBlank` constraint dinamically according to the selected choice, on `PostSetData` event. [Look here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) for more information.